# Make rule using `$<` only adding one object to archive library

Tags: gnu-make, archive

I feel stupid, but I cannot find the solution myself:

I have a `Makefile` that correctly builds objects from C source, and I want to place `$(OBJECTS)` in an archive library.
I'm using GNU Make 4.0.

```makefile
x.a: $(OBJECTS)
        echo "$< ($(OBJECTS))"
        $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $<
```

(Lines are indented with TABs in original. The echo was added for debugging purposes only, The `$(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $<` was copied from `make`'s internal rules)

Make outputs (at the end after the objects were built):

```text
echo "log_thread/log_thread.o (log_thread/log_thread.o log_thread/thread.o)"
log_thread/log_thread.o (log_thread/log_thread.o log_thread/thread.o)
ar rv x.a log_thread/log_thread.o
ar: creating x.a
a - log_thread/log_thread.o
```

So I expect both objects modules to be added to the library `x.a`, but `$<` only contains one object module, as opposed to `$(OBJECTS)`).

My Make knowledge may be a little rusty, maybe that's why I don't get it.
Of course both object modules exist, and the output was created after having removed `x.a` (the original file is a bit more complex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where the confusion lies:
The `$<` automatic variable contains the first prerequisite only, as per definition.
See the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#index-_0024_003c).

To get all prerequisites newer than the target, `$?` is the correct automatic variable.
So the correct rule probably is:

```make
x.a: $(OBJECTS)
        echo "$? ($(OBJECTS))"
        $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $?
```

Comment: OK, what I've learned is: "Never trust a built-in rule".

Comment: OK, if that's what you want to take away from this I guess I can't stop you.  But the documentation of these variables is clear, and all the built-in rules are correct and trustworthy.